# An algebraic way to prove some identity

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I found the following fact accidentially.

**Fact**:  Let $d, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq d+2$. Suppose $\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n$ are distinct complex numbers. Then the following holds;
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \prod_{j=1 \\ j \neq k}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_k - \lambda_j} \right] \lambda_k^d = 0.$$

I was able to prove this via complex analysis. In fact consider the left side as a rational function of $\lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and call it $f$. $f$ has sigularities at $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{n-1}$. However calculating the residue of $f$ at $\lambda_k$, we get
$$ \mbox{Res}(f, \lambda_k) = - \left[ \prod_{j=1 \\ j\neq k}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\lambda_k - \lambda_j} \right] \lambda_k^d + \left[ \prod_{j=1 \\ j\neq k}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\lambda_k - \lambda_j} \right] \lambda_k^d = 0$$
hence we see that those singularities are actually removable. Thus $f$ is entire. And since $n\geq d+2$, $f(\lambda_n) \to 0$ when $\lambda_n \to \infty$. By Liouville's theorem $f = 0$, as claimed. 
So my question is whether we can prove this identity in a purely algebraic way. I want to know this because, if there is a way, probably this identity can be extended to other fields than $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I can't answer your question but your product looks suspiciously like the multiplicative inverse of the discriminant of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from Lagrange interpolation. If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$
are distinct, and $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ then
$$P(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k:k\ne j}P(\lambda_j)\frac{x-\lambda_k}{\lambda_j-\lambda_k}.$$
To prove this, call the RHS $Q(x)$ and note that $Q(x)$ is a polynomial
of degree $\le n-1$ with $P(\lambda_j)=Q(\lambda_j)$. Their difference
has $n$ zeros but has degree less than $n$.

Take $P(x)=x^d$ for $d\le n-2$. Then
$$x^d=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k:k\ne j}\lambda_j^d\frac{x-\lambda_k}{\lambda_j-\lambda_k}.$$
Comparing $x^{n-1}$ coefficients,
$$0=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k:k\ne j}\frac{\lambda_j^d}{\lambda_j-\lambda_k}.$$

Comment: I didn't know about the Lagrange interpolation but your explanation is easy to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x)=(x-\lambda_1)\cdots  (x-\lambda_n)$, $F(x)=\frac{x^d}{P(x)}$. Then the decomposition of $F$ in simple fraction is 
$$F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{x-\lambda_k}$$
We have $c_k=\lambda_k^d/(P^{\prime}(\lambda_k))$. Now multiply by $x$, let $x\to \infty$, and take in account that $n\geq d+2$.

Comment: It's worth noting that $P'(\lambda_k)=\prod_{i\neq k} (\lambda_k-\lambda_i)$

Comment: +1 But it still isn't an algebraic proof, since you use a limit.

Comment: This solution is much better than mine, but I'm wondering whether this identity holds for other fields.

Comment: Interestingly, if $d=n-1$, this shows that the sum is $1$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew Ok.. You can also multiply by $P(x)$, you find $x^d$, and the coeffcient of $x^{n-1}$ in the product  has to be $0$.

Comment: @MatsudaToyomu If you multiply the left side by $\prod_{i\neq j}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)$ (where the product is taken over all $i,j$) then you get a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k]$ which is everywhere zero as a function on $\mathbb C^{n}$, except possibly when some $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$. This can be shown to mean that this polynomial is identically zero, so it is true in all fields.

Comment: @Kelenner, Thomas Andrews I still need time to understand what you say but thank you for great help.