Show that $\sum_{j=1}^n\left((-1)^{j-1}\prod_{\substack{1 \leq k < l \leq n \\ k \ne j, \, l \ne j}} (x_k-x_l)\right)=0$
I was trying to prove this equality:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\prod_{j=1,j\neq k}^n\left(\frac{1}{x_k-x_j}\right)\right)=0$$
where $x_k\ne x_j, \forall k\ne j$?
I've shown it for the cases where $n=1,2,3,4$. As an example I'll give you the case $n=3$.
First, for simplicity, let's define $x=x_1,y=x_2$ and $z=x_3$. Now we have the following:
$$\frac{1}{(x-y)(x-z)}+\frac{1}{(y-x)(y-z)}+\frac{1}{(z-x)(z-y)}=\frac{(y-x)(y-z)(z-x)(z-y)+(x-y)(x-z)(z-x)(z-y)+(x-y)(x-z)(y-x)(y-z)}{(x-y)(x-z)(y-x)(y-z)(z-x)(z-y)}$$
This is equal to $0$ iff the numerator is equal to $0$, therefore it is enough for us to show that numerator is equal to $0$. Looking at the numerator we can factor out $(z-x)(z-y)$ and since that product obviously isn't equal to $0$, we need to show that the following is equal to $0$:
$$(y-x)(y-z)+(x-y)(x-z)+(-1)^{3-1}(x-y)(y-x)$$
Again, we can factor out $(y-x)$, which of course isn't equal to $0$, so again we need to show that $$(y-z)+(-1)^{3-2}(x-z)+(-1)^{3-1}(x-y)=0$$
Which is trivial to show.
This last part, in all the cases I've done, has led me to finding out, that for $n$, we need to show that
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\left((-1)^{j-1}\prod_{\substack{1 \leq k < l \leq n \\ k \ne j, \, l \ne j}} (x_k-x_l)\right)=0$$
But this is the part I'm struggling with, I tried using both induction and some algebraic manipulations, but still failed. How would you go about proving this for all $n$?

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276370/42969

@AnneBauval my problem actually comes from complex analysis, too, and it looks similiar, though not the same. But I'm trying to do exactly the opposite.. I was given a contour integral $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z-z_1)\dots(z-z_n)}$, where $\gamma$ is a simply closed contour, and $z_1,\dots,z_n$ are inside of the area determined by $\gamma$. So I'm using residues and trying to show their sum is equal to $0$. I know there are other methods to do this, but I want to try this one. Also, I'm not asking for the solution of sum in the beginning, but rather the one I wrote in the end.

@MartinR I don't want to prove that sum is equal to 0, but the one I got in the end.

Aren’t you missing factors of $-1$ in your last equation (also the equation in the title)? In the current form, for $n=3$, I get $(x_2-x_3)+(x_1-x_3)+(x_1-x_2) = 2(x_1-x_3)$ which is certainly not zero.

@Pranay ah yes, totally forgot about that. Thank you.

Think of the expression on the LHS as a polynomial in $x_1$. Its degree is $n-2$ because the $j=1$ doesn’t contain any $x_1$, whereas the other terms contain exactly $n-2$ factors involving $x_1$. However, this polynomial has $n-1$ obvious roots given by $x_1 = x_i$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$. Indeed, the terms $j\ne 1,i$ vanish identically under this substitution, whereas the $j=1$ and $j=i$ terms cancel each other. But this is impossible unless the polynomial is the zero polynomial.

How is it obvious that $x_i, i=2,\dots,n$ are roots of the given polynomial? What about the constant term. If you look at the $n=3$ case, wouldn't the polynomial $P(z)$ for example be equal to $y-z$, since that is the free term. Maybe I'm misunderstading you. Furthermore, can you clarify this part: "Indeed, the terms $j\ne 1,i$ vanish identically under this substitution, whereas the $j=1$ and $j=i$ terms cancel each other. But this is impossible unless the polynomial is the zero polynomial."? Thank you for answering, btw.

@bb_823 I think it’s better to stick to the sum you wrote instead of expanding the polynomial in powers of $x_1$. In the sum, the $j\ne1,i$ terms contain a factor of $(x_1-x_i)$, so they all vanish when you substitute $x_1=x_i$. The terms $j=1$ and $j=i$ don’t vanish by themselves but they cancel each other. For example, in the $n=3$ case, the $j=1$ term is $(x_2-x_3)$ and the $j=2$ term is $-(x_1-x_3)$, so when you substitute $x_1=x_2$, they don’t vanish separately, but they cancel each other.

@bb_823 in your comment, you also said $P(z) = y-z$. That’s not correct. See my comment above.

my bad. Ok, I understand it now. Thank you.

Just to ask you one more question. Wouldn't the assumption that $x_1\ne x_i, i=2,\dots,n$ (where we x_1 is constant) from the start lead us to the fact that $P(x_1)=0$, without the need to look at the degrees of polynomials? Since x_1 shouldn't pass through any of the $x_i$ points as a variable, unless polynomial is equal to $0$.

@bb_823 I don’t completely understand your question but perhaps the following helps. Let’s use a different symbol, say $X_1$ for the variable in the polynomial. What I showed is that $X_1=x_i$ is a root for $i=2,\ldots,n$, so the polynomial  $P(X_1)$ must be the zero polynomial. You can then substitute $X_1=x_1$ to get the equation you want. Perhaps there are other ways to prove directly without resorting to polynomials but to me this is much cleaner.
